# When a guy said "I only just caught the train", had he catch the train?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Oxford Dictionary (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/just) gives this definition about "just"

> Barely; by a little.

and these examples

```
‘inflation fell to just over 4 percent’
‘I got here just after nine’
‘I only just caught the train’
```

I am aware that the first 2 means "by a little more", such as 4.01%, 9:02.

I have some difficulties on the last one, had he catch the train?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, he caught the train but was close to missing it.